# Select div where text is equal to

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to select the div where the value is for ex. "5".
This is my situation:

I have div's like this:

```
<div class="element">
    <div class="number>5</div>
    <div class="symbol">..</div>
</div>
<div class="element">
    <div class="number>6</div>
    <div class="symbol">..</div>
</div>
...
```

Now I want to selected the div witch class = number where the value is equal to 5 out of a bunch of div's.
How can I do this the best way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var $div = $('div.number').filter(function(){
  return $.trim($(this).text()) === "5";
});
```

Demo `---->` http://jsfiddle.net/nGkYu/1/

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery's [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/), apply this selector to get only element that contain something

```
$(".number:contains('5')").doSomething()..
```

note that this solution will return all `<div>`s **containing** "5" including "512"..

Comment: will returns div with text equal 54321 too

Comment: sorry, you are right obviously. @pXL 's method is the correct way of doing that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
$(".number").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == "5") {
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative in case the number can change here is a function which can be passed the number as a parameter.

```
function findDiv(numToFind, clsToSearch){
   var num = parseFloat(numToFind);
   if(typeof num == "number"){
      var divsIwant = $('.'+clsToSearch).filter(function(){
          var curDiv = $.trim($(this).text());
          return curDiv == num;
      });
      return divsIwant;
   } else {
      return false;
}

var hereAreMyDivs = findDiv(5, "number");
```